# simulations for observational studies

Tags: r, simulation, causality, observational-study

I am trying to get a better understanding of the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.01332.pdf) "Causal inference using invariant prediction: identification and confidence intervals". Part of it is trying to replicate their simulation study (I could not find the code used). In appendix G. it is written that,

"We first sample a directed acyclic graph with $p$ nodes that is
common to both scenarios. In order to do so, we choose a random topological order and
then connect two nodes with a probability of $k/(p − 1)$. This leads to an average degree
of $k$. Given the graph structure, we then sample non-zero linear coefficients with a random sign and a random absolute value... "

What does it mean that two nodes are connected? Is it that the covariates are correlated? How does one implement it?